# How to show that $f(x)\ge 0 \implies \int_a^x fdt \ge 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is clear to me thinking about integration like area under a curve, but how can it be proven? (assuming $f$ is continuous and using the fundamental theorem of calculus, and $\forall x\in[a,b]$)

Comment: For any partition $P$ you must have $L(f,P) \ge 0$, hence the integral must be non negative. Neither continuity nor fundamental theorem of calculus are necessary here. Only integrability of $f$.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to somehow use the fundamental theorem of calculus for this?

Comment: Define $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$. What is $F(a)$?  What is $F'$?  Once you know $F'$, can you see that $F$ is increasing?  Given $F(a)$ and that $F$ is increasing, can you see that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt\geq 0.$

Comment: Got it,thank you. But what is $F(0)$?

Comment: I guess I should say "non-decreasing" rather than "increasing", in the event that $f(x)=0$ over some interval of positive length in the domain of $f.$

Comment: This problem is in desperate need of quantifiers.

Comment: I added the quantifier. Thank you everyone for the responses

Comment: @RandyE [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/115951).

Comment: @GitGud Thanks! I've wondered about this terminological problem for a while, but never found a good answer.  So I should say "weakly increasing" rather than "increasing" or "non-decreasing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $x\ge a$ in the integral $\int_a^x f(t)dt$

Let $f(x)$ be the derivative of a function $F(x)$

Since $f(x)\ge0$, the function $F(x)$ must be weakly increasing, and since $x\ge a$ we have $F(x)\ge F(a)$

We know from the fundamental theorem of calculus that
$$
\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt=F(x)-F(a)
$$
Can you see it now?

Comment: I do see it now, thank you!

Comment: If $\int_a^x fdt=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, would this imply $f(x)=0$?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, yes. But not in general; take a function which is zero except at a single point.

Comment: @user42 My proof works if $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$ in the interval used as limits on the integral.

Comment: Yes it does,thank you

Answer (score 2):

You know that $$f\geq g\implies \int f\geq \int g,$$
therefore,
$$f\geq 0\implies \int f\geq \int 0=0$$

Comment: To the downvoter: what's wrong here ?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter and your answer is correct and the simplest way of proving it, however the question stated `using the fundamental theorem of calculus`

Comment: It's correct in the sense that it obviously answer the problem, but - in addition to what Kristoffer said - it's also obvious that such a problem wouldn't come up after this result was proven.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use $\int_{a}^{x} (f-0)dt \geq0$. Now split the integrals and take the second one to the RHS

Comment: How do you assume that $\int_{a}^{x} (f-0)dt \geq0$?