# Existence of integral implies the existence of a limit

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f$ is a decreasing continuous function on $[0, \infty)$. And the integral of $f(x)/\sqrt{x}$ on $[0, \infty)$ exists.
>
> Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{x}f(x)=0$.

**My work**. I think we should prove the limit exists firstly. Then everything would be quite easy.

Suppose that $\exists \epsilon>0$, $\forall N>0$, $\exists x_N>N$, s.t $\sqrt{x_N}f(x_N)>\epsilon$. We would find that $f(x_N)/\sqrt{x_N}>\epsilon/x_N$.

But I can't go any further. Any one has some better idea?

Comment: By $f$ being "non-increasing", do you mean "$f$ is not monotonically increasing", i.e. it has at least one place where it decreases, or "$f$ never increases"? I would call that last one a decreasing function.

Comment: @Arthur non-increasing means that if $a>b$ then $f(a)\le f(b)$ that is it never increases.

Comment: @skyking To me, a function being non-increasing is a function which is not an increasing function. What you have there is exactly what a decreasing function is defined as.

Comment: Typically, a monotonically nonincreasing function is a function which is _never_ increasing. I emphasize that "monotonically" should be specified.

Comment: @Arthur Maybe in your book, other books say decreasing means that if $a>b$ then $f(a)<f(b)$.

Comment: @Arthur the same thing that separates $<$ from $\le$.

Comment: @skyking In my book that's called _strictly_ decreasing, same thing that separates "less than" from "strictly less than".

Comment: @skyking Sometimes we would say it's 'strictly'

Comment: @Arthur Forgot it and try to focus on the question.

Comment: [For the benefit of everybody...](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115951/153693)

Comment: @Arthur Yes, the definition of "decreasing" may differ slightly from book to book (and therefore for that term you have to read carefully), but I've never seen any ambiguity about the terms "non-increasing" and "strictly decreasing".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint. Since $f$ is decreasing in $[0, \infty)$, then also $f(x)/\sqrt{x}$ is decreasing in $(0, \infty)$: if $0<x<y$ then
$$\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\geq \frac{f(y)} {\sqrt{x}}\geq\frac{f(y)}{\sqrt{y}}.$$
Hence, for $x>0$,
$$0\leq f(x)\sqrt{x}=2\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}} (x - x/2) \leq 2\int_{x/2}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt.$$
Now use the fact that the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt$ is finite to show that the r.h.s. goes to zero as $x\to+\infty$.

P.S. Note that $f(x)$ is non negative. If $f(x_0)<0$ for some $x_0>0$ then $-f(x)\geq -f(x_0)> 0$ and 
$$-\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt\geq (-f(x_0))\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt=+\infty$$
which contradicts the fact that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt$ is finite.