# Terminology: Monotone vs increasing

Tags: terminology

In the current version of [my book](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/volume-1.pdf) (related with order theory) I used the term *monotone* to denote $\forall x,y:(x\geq y\Rightarrow f(x)\geq f(y))$.

1. Should this usage of the term *monotone* be considered correct, or should the term *increasing* be used instead?
2. If I switch to the term *increasing*, how to reformulate such phrase as "Monotonicity is obvious." or "by monotonicity of composition"?

Comment: *non-decreasing* would be more accurate.

Comment: I think the mathematical community has been kind of stuck for quite a while with ambiguous terminology for this concept. Look at this question for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115912/why-do-we-use-non-increasing-instead-of-decreasing?rq=1

Comment: Increasing is stronger than monotonous. "Monotonous growth is obvious."

Comment: It would be an excellent service if you could present a reasonable and consistent terminology in your book.

Comment: @LukasKofler I think, _non-decreasing_ would instead mean $\forall x,y:(x\ngeq y\Rightarrow f(x)\ngeq f(y))$. Or do I mistake?

Comment: @LukasKofler Or does _non-decreasing_ mean $\forall x,y:(x\geq y\Rightarrow f(x)\nleq f(y))$?

Comment: Note it is order theory, not calculus